# Eloquent: How to sync in one to many relations without deleting anything (FK is nullable)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many, laravel-blade

A branch may have **zero**(*) or only one holiday plan. A holiday plan may be "linked" (attached) to zero or many branches.

(*) **this is very important: it is a `Foreign Key` which may be `null`**

[image]

#### Model

Here is my `Branch` Model:

```php
class Branch extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'branch';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'holiday_plan_id'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function holidayPlan()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\HolidayPlan', 'id', 'holiday_plan_id');
    }
}
```

---

And here is my `HolidayPlan` Model:

```php
class HolidayPlan extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'holiday_plan';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function branches()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Branch', 'holiday_plan_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

#### View

Now I want to link/unlink a holiday plan to different branches

```php
$branches = Branch::all();
$plan = HolidayPlan::find(1);
```

---

```php
@foreach($branches as $branch)
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="branch[]"
        value="{{ $branch->id }}"{{ ($branch->holiday_plan_id == $plan->id) ? ' checked' : '' }}>
    {{ $branch->name }}
</label>
@endforeach
```

---

#### Controller

```php
public function linkBranches($planId, Request $request) // post
{
    $plan = HolidayPlan::where('id', $planId)->first();
    $branches = Branch::findMany($request->input('branch'));
    //
    $this->solution1($plan, $branches); // see next
    //
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

---

#### Possible solutions (not working)

```php
private function solution1(HolidayPlan $plan, $branches)
{
    $plan->branches()->sync($branches); // Not working because this function is for Many-to-Many relations
}
```

---

```php
private function solution2(HolidayPlan $plan, $branches)
{
    $plan->branches()->delete(); // This will delete my branches, which is not what I want to do, of course
    $plan->branches()->saveMany($branches);
}
```

---

```php
private function solution3(HolidayPlan $plan, $branches)
{
    foreach($plan->branches as $branch) {
        $branch->holiday_plan_id = null;
        $branch->save();
    }
    $plan->branches()->saveMany($branches); // Not working; I don't know why: strange behavior. Maybe because of locks; I'm not sure. One time it detaches all branches, and only next time it attaches them again.
}
```

---

#### Finally

Actually, a raw SQL would be:

```php
UPDATE branch SET holiday_plan_id = NULL WHERE holiday_plan_id = 1;
UPDATE branch SET holiday_plan_id = 1 WHERE branch.id IN (2, 5, 7)/* for example */;
```

But how to do this using Eloquent functions and relations (without raw sql)?

---

#### Edit

I've edited my `Branch` model relationship, however `solution3` still doesn't work (when I try to add an already existing `holiday_plan_id`, it doesn't add it = it becomes null):

```php
public function holidayPlan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\HolidayPlan', 'holiday_plan_id');
}
```

Comment: *without deleting anything*, well it depends on your table.. foreign keys (the `holiday_plan_fk`) on most database can be set to either: (1) cascade delete, (2) do nothing, (3) set null. on (1) when you delete the one row that the foreign key refers to, it will also delete the other row(s). (2) will just, restrict you doing anything on `mysql` if the id of the particular row still referenced on the other row. on (3), it will simply sets the foreign key to null.. so.. tell us what is your database engine and the migration or at least sql script that generates the database. cheers!

Comment: see these: (1) what [cascade delete](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/44962/105215), (2) [do nothing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13574/105215), and (3) [set null do](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/198383/foreign-key-on-delete-set-null). hope i dont misunderstand your question..

Comment: This is another issue. Thank you for information. I'm deleting anything.

Comment: ahh, tried `$plan->branches()->dissociate()`?

Comment: In your models you are specifying column names. Those are completely redundant. You should also use belongsTo in your Branch to HolidayPlan model.

Comment: Yes, I get error message: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::dissociate()`. Even with my new `belongsTo` relationship. It reads, it deletes creates, but cannot update.

Comment: @Mazzy the column names are not redundant, because the application I'm working on, does not follow Laravel-convension-rules. I fixed names for my example to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @LowLevel thanks that explains that part. You cannot do SET NULL via eloquent associate, sync, and dissociate or hasMany in that sense, it simply expects the relationship to be there and deletes or creates it. Having a `branch` without a `holidayplan` is actually strange. I think the question would be is this something you really need? (the nullable FK) if so, please explain why you need it

Comment: @Mazzy it is something I really need. because you may create branches even if you haven't created any holiday plan yet. And you may remove a holiday plan without deleting any branch. Or you may uncheck branches from within Holiday-Plans page, so that you can link another plans to them again.

Comment: @Mazzy, there are plenty of applications using nullable-FK fields. Imagine a Flight Route which is attached to a certain Flight, or a Configuration, which is attached to a System or a Device, etc. You can use One-to-One + One-to-Many tables too to achieve this, but it is redundant.

Comment: `if($plan->branches !== null){//$plan->branches()->dissociate();`

Comment: Also, I think you should use `$plan->branches()->attach() and $plan->branches->detach();` Remember to check if there actually even is a collection of eloquent models in  $plan->branches() or just a query builder instance(maybe get the result set)

Comment: attach and detach are not working. I know I have used them before. But I don't know anymore why ))

Comment: @user3647971 I love Laravel/Eloquent, however I cannot understand why we use so many different keywords instead of save or update everywhere.

Comment: @LowLevel I see. Well for images that can be attached to anything I use Image::updateOrCreate and then use Sync with the array of id's of images

Answer (score 3):

Temporary Solution:

```
public function solution4(HolidayPlan $plan, $inputBranches)
{
    $oldLinks = $plan->branches;
    $plan->branches()->saveMany($inputBranches);
    foreach ($oldLinks as $oldLink) {
        if (! $inputBranches->contains($oldLink)) {
            $oldLink->holiday_plan_id = null;
            $oldLink->save();
        }
    }
}
```